# How to set opacity on a colour resource?

Tags: android, colors

I know that I can set opacity by adding an alpha channel in hex (#AARRGGBB), but what if I want to use a value from my colors.xml that I otherwise do not wish to add opacity to?

For example, I use a dark blue colour of #074EB2 in my colors.xml, as such:

```
<color name="DarkBlue">#074EB2</color>
```

Now, I have a custom button background with a border. I want the border to use this dark blue colour, but have opacity added. The button looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/DarkBlue"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

How can I add opacity? Do I need to add a new value to colors.xml with opacity? ie, `<color name="DarkBlueTransparent">#80074EB2</color>`? The problem I see with this is that it isn't scalable - what if I have somewhere else that needs this colour 80% opacity? 90%? My colors.xml file would explode with different values for how transparent I want things.

Comment: Either make more resources or set the opacity of the container to whatever you need.

Comment: "My colors.xml file would explode with different values for how transparent I want things." Really? you really need so many transparency levels to various colors? Like DarkBlue70Percent and DarkBlue71Percent?

Comment: Over exaggeration, but you get the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do dynamic opacity in xml. But you can apply alpha dynamically in java side.

use this method to apply alpha to your color.

```
public static int getColorWithAlpha(int yourColor, int alpha) {
    int red = Color.red(yourColor);
    int blue = Color.blue(yourColor);
    int green = Color.green(yourColor);
    return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
}
```

now get the color with alpha by calling the method

```
blueWithAlpha = getColorWithAlpha(darkBlue, 120);
```

120 is your alpha level

> Alpha level should have to be between 0 to 225

now apply your color to your button

```
mButton.setBackgroundColor(blueWithAlpha);
```